# Heroku : unable to access log

Tags: logging, heroku

For several hours, I cannot access to the logs of my apps, "heroku logs" give me the error "Could not connect to logging service", or sometimes "Could not create Logplex session. Please try again later.".

Can you help me?

Comment: This sounds like some specific issue on Heroku. Irrelevant here.

Comment: What app infrastructure are you using? If it's Ruby On Rails, [you might need rails12-factor gem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails4)

Comment: It's a Play! 1.2.7 app

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a question best directed at Heroku support.

Comment: Correct answer. This happened to me, but turned out the logging service was down. You can check statuses by logging into Heroku and going here: https://status.heroku.com/.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I deployed an app for the first time. Just give it a few minutes, it seems that the logging system takes a while to setup after 1st deployment.